# Creating a CSS 'path' on hover

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, css-transitions

I'm trying to generate a 'nice' CSS menu using (mainly) CSS, but with a *tiny* bit of [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) as well:

My overall idea is:

```
+------------------------+
|                        |
|                        |
|         +---+          |
|         |   |          |
|         |___|          | <-- Hover this center piece
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
+------------------------+

+------------------------+
|     _                  |
|    |\                  | <-- All start moving up to top of screen
|      \  +---+          |
|         |   |          |
|         |___|          |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
+------------------------+

+------------------------+
| +---+                  |
| |   |                  |
| |___|                  |
|                        |
|  || All, but one       |
|  || moves down         |
|  \/                    |
|                        |
+------------------------+

+------------------------+
| +---+                  |
| |   |                  |
| |___|                  |
|                        |
|        One stays,      |
| +---+  the rest move this way
| |   |  --->            |
| |___|                  |
+------------------------+

+------------------------+
| +---+                  |
| |   |                  |
| |___|              ^   | The rest move up
|                    |   |
|                    |   |
| +---+            +---+ |
| |   |            |   | |
| |___|            |___| |<-- Another stays
+------------------------+
```

Complete:

```
+------------------------+
| +---+            +---+ |
| | 1 |            | 4 | |
| |___|            |___| |
|                        |
|                        |
| +---+            +---+ |
| | 2 |            | 3 | |
| |___|            |___| |
+------------------------+
```

However, that presumes that there will be four div children, So I'm trying to generate a way of 'determining the angle/position' in jQuery (which, to be honest, isn't working too well).

---

Similar design:

[image]

---

So in the end, since there are four divs, they will be at 90 degree intervals from the center (360/4 divs = 90 degrees apart).

If there were, say, six child divs;

```
360/6 = 60 degrees
```

So they will be evenly spaced out at 60 degree intervals.

---

I'll be adding animation as well between them, so hence why I've been playing about with rotations, etc., but I just can't seem to get to grips with it:

My current sample is:

```js
$(".wrap").hover(function(){
    var x =$(this).children().length; //Counts '.circles'
    var degree = 360 / x; //Gets angle
    var percent = 100 / x;
    var curPercent = percent;
    $(this).children().each(function (index) {
        $(this).css("transform","rotate(" + degree*index + "deg)");
        $(this).css("top",percent + "px");
        $(this).css("left",percent + "px");

        percent = percent + curPercent;
    });
});
```

```css
.wrap{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}
.wrap:hover .circle{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.circle{
    transition: all 0.8s;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    left: calc(50% - 25px);
    background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="circle">1</div>
    <div class="circle">2</div>
    <div class="circle">3</div>
    <div class="circle">4</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/rdcms62q/)

---

Would anyone:

- (A): Know how to get the divs to 'rotate' the specified angle or distance in relevance to the parent specified in the jQuery code?
- (B): Get the 'animation' to reset on hover out?
- (C): <strike>*Have any idea what I'm talking about?*</strike>

---

**Similar implementations (although not exact):**

- [Here](http://beaucollins.github.io/radial-menu/)
- [This more so](http://codepen.io/adny/pen/iekyA) - but this uses [Sass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) (not wanted)

Comment: Do you know @keyframes? Cause it looks like you can do what you want entirely with css...

Comment: @Pa3k.m: Even degree calculation based on no. of children?

Comment: @Pa3k.m: only problem with keyframes is that It'll be looking for an end position (which i won't know until jquery's run) and also there's a lot of prefixes to add for it.

Comment: @downvoter could you please explain as to why?

Comment: @jbutler483 so you're sayin the number of children divs are undefined?

Comment: @Pa3k.m: *However, that presumes that there will be four div children, So i'm trying to generate a way of 'determining the angle/position' in jquery (which, tbh, isn't working too well).*

Comment: That sentence is not at all clear, which is why Pa3k.m asked. What is the maximum and minimum number of  sprites/divs you wish to animate? When do you want to determine the angles? During the animation, before it, or after it? When is the number of divs determined - when the HTML is generated, when the page loads, or while the user is using it? (If the last, exactly when?)

Comment: Since the page will have *dynamic content*, the angles cannot be set (obviously), and hence why the 'angles' must be determined during the actual hover. You can also see that in my snippet, i'm counting the length, the accepted answer also using the length. So, using common sense, I don't think 'after it' really makes any sense here.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Using a different approach you'll get a slightly different effect. You can play with the times of the `setTimeout` and the `transition` to modify the behavior.

### [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasny/rdcms62q/24/)

```js
+ function() {
  var to;
  $(".wrap").on('mouseenter', function() {
    var circles = $(this).children();
    var degree = (2 * Math.PI) / circles.length; //calc delta angle
    var transforms = [];

    // Calculate the position for each circle
    circles.each(function(index) {
        var x = 100 * Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI + degree * (-1 * index - 0.5));
        var y = 100 * Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI + degree * (-1 * index - 0.5));

      transforms.push('translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)');
    });

    // Function to moves all the circles
    // We'll pop a circle each time and than call this function recursively
    function moveCircles() {
      var transform = transforms.shift();
      circles.css('transform', transform);

      circles.splice(0, 1);
      if (circles.length) to = setTimeout(moveCircles, 400);
    }

    moveCircles();
  });

  $(".wrap").on('mouseleave', function() {
    var circles = $(this).children().css('transform', '');
    clearTimeout(to);
  });
}();
```

```css
   .wrap {
     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
     background: red;
     position: relative;
     transform-origin: center center;
     transition: all 0.8s;
   }
   .circle {
     transition: all 0.8s;
     position: absolute;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 50px;
     top: calc(50% - 25px);
     left: calc(50% - 25px);
     background: tomato;
     border-radius: 50%;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circle">1</div>
  <div class="circle">2</div>
  <div class="circle">3</div>
  <div class="circle">4</div>
  <div class="circle">5</div>
  <div class="circle">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty awesome. Cheers Really liking the markup actually :):)

Comment: @jbutler483 The `(-1 * index - 1.5)` was giving odd positions for an uneven number of circles. Using a -90 degree offset and using `(-1 * index - 0.5)` gives a better result. :)

Comment: Once again thank you for this. you can see my take on your example [here](http://codepen.io/jbutler483/pen/EaQxyW) - so thank you :)

Answer (score 23):

```js
function rotateStep($this, $circle, angle) {
    $this.animate({
        rotation: angle
    }, {
        step: function(now, fx) {
            $this.css({
                transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
            });
            $circle.css({
                transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(' + -now + 'deg)'
            });
        }
    });
}

$('.wrap').hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $circleWrappers = $this.find('.circleWrapper'),
        angleOffset = 360 / $circleWrappers.length,
        angle = - angleOffset / 2,
        distance = Math.min($this.width(), $this.height()) / 2;
    
    $circleWrappers.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $circle = $(this).find('.circle');
        $circle.animate({ top: -distance });
        rotateStep($this, $circle, angle);
        angle -= angleOffset;
    });
}, function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $circleWrappers = $this.find('.circleWrapper');
    
    $circleWrappers.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $circle = $(this).find('.circle');
        $circle.animate({ top: 0 });
        rotateStep($this, $circle, 0);
    });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    transition:all 0.8s;
    transform-origin: center center;
}
.circleWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
.circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="circleWrapper"><div class="circle">1</div></div>
    <div class="circleWrapper"><div class="circle">2</div></div>
    <div class="circleWrapper"><div class="circle">3</div></div>
    <div class="circleWrapper"><div class="circle">4</div></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ffx7Lh1/1/)

Comment: Thank you for this, looking through your jquery I don't think i'd ever have gotten my implementation working, so thank you for that. But it's very clear and I can sort of see how it's working, so cheers :)

Comment: Added the hover out effect too

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: Although this is a great approach, I think if you see the accepted answer, I think you'll possibly agree with the solution given.

Comment: @jbutler483 seems like the other answer fits the question even better so I have no problem with that :)

Comment: congrats on the 10k BTW