# Div elements to follow a curved path with CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes, css-transforms

So the basic idea is 1 - 9 seats at a curved table as though you are looking at them through first person view. I'm trying to get `div` elements which would be seats to flow on the outside of another `div` element that has a border radius to make it a semi oblong circle. I've found a few examples with an element being animated to flow across the container in an arc, but I will need the div/seats to be static. I am looking for any ideas or examples that can lead me in the right path.

Comment: Here is a very rough idea on how to go about implementing it - http://jsfiddle.net/5c59m5q4/. Not close enough to post as an answer and I don't have the time right now to tune it.

Comment: That will work perfectly to get me started. And I actually just thought about something similar when I went on a walk.  Thank you Harry, if you want to put it down as an answer I'll be glad to make it the answer.

Comment: please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497425/creating-a-css-path-on-hover), as it resembles a familiar concept to the one you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Finding points on ellipse and translating:**

If your oblong circle resembles an ellipse then you can find points on the ellipse using mathematical formula and then translate each `div` element to that particular point.

[Mathematical formula](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamellipse.html) for calculating point `(x,y)` on an ellipse is`(a * cos(t), b * sin(t))`. In this formula, `a` represents the radius of the ellipse in x-axis, `b` represents the radius of the ellipse in the y-axis and `t` represents the angle in radians. Angle in radians = Angle in degrees * pi / 180.

To make use of this approach, we do the following:

- Place the `div` elements absolutely at the centre point of the ellipse.
- Calculate the `(x,y)` corresponding to each angle and translate the `div` to its place by using `transform: translateX(...) translateY(...)`. The angles are in steps of 22.5 deg because there are a total 9 elements to be placed within 180 degrees.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 12.5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
div > div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%) translateY(50%);
}
div > div:after {
  background: red;
}
div > div:nth-child(n+4):after {
  background: orange;
}
div > div:nth-child(n+7):after {
  background: green;
}
div > div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(-300px) translateY(0px);
}
div > div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-277.17px) translateY(-76.5px);
}
div > div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(-212.13px) translateY(-141.42px);
}
div > div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateX(-114.80px) translateY(-184.77px);
}
div > div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translateX(0px) translateY(-200px);
}
div > div:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translateX(114.80px) translateY(-184.77px);
}
div > div:nth-child(7) {
  transform: translateX(212.13px) translateY(-141.42px);
}
div > div:nth-child(8) {
  transform: translateX(277.17px) translateY(-76.5px);
}
div > div:nth-child(9) {
  transform: translateX(300px) translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

[image]

<sup>**Note:** The coordinates are approximate values and hence they may not align 100% correctly.</sup>

---

**Using rotation and scale transform:** (original idea)

The below snippet provides a very rough idea on how to position the **elements along a circle**. It is by no means a complete output but you can adapt it to fit your needs.

The components are very simple:

- One container element which is a circle and serves as the reference element against which the seats are positioned.
- 9 individual `div` elements for each seat. All of them have 50% `width` of the container and 50% `height`.
- A pseudo-element (`:after`) attached to the child `div` elements that produce the circle/dot like seats and they are absolutely positioned at the bottom of the container.
- Each child `div` element is rotated by `180/(n-1)` deg as we need them to be positioned around a semicircle.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
div > div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
div > div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(22.5deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(67.5deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(112.5deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(157.5deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
div > div:after {
  background: red;
}
div > div:nth-child(n+4):after {
  background: orange;
}
div > div:nth-child(n+7):after {
  background: green;
}

/* Just for demo */

.container{
  transition: all 1s;
}  
.container:hover {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

There is a **simple method to convert the above into an oblong circle** and that would be to scale the container in the X-axis. One point to note is that the children would also get scaled and hence would need to be reverse transformed.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scaleX(1.25);
  transform-origin: left;
}
div > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}
div > div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
div > div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(22.5deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(67.5deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(112.5deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(157.5deg);
}
div > div:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
div > div:after {
  background: red;
}
div > div:nth-child(n+4):after {
  background: orange;
}
div > div:nth-child(n+7):after {
  background: green;
}

/* Just for demo */

.container {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.container:hover {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  transform: scaleX(1.25);
  transform-origin: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The first method is the perfect and recommended approach as it doesn't cause any distortion to the `div` elements. The second is rough idea which avoids complex trigonometric calculations.

Comment: Holy mathmatics caped wonder!!! You went all out on this one. Thank you for the detailed answer. I always wondered why so much math was part of the Computer Science curriculum, and now I know. I'll try to use the first answer.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Actually, after looking at it a little more I see one problem. I need the web page to be a responsive design.  So if I use the equation I will need to have absolute heights and widths defined. And setting values through javascript on page resize would be costly. Do you know if the first answer would work with percentages?

Comment: @jhorton: The first answer would need JS to be responsive because the positions are calculated based on the X & Y radius of the ellipse. The second one can be made responsive without any extra calculations but as noted in the answer, it needs a scale transform to become oblong and that would mean the `div` inside would also look scaled.