# placing 5 images in a circle with css

Tags: css

I have a div which should hold 5 images (round shapes) and those shapes should rotate (but that's not the problem, I can do that with jQuery). The problem is how to position the images trough css so they have an equal distance from the other images and also each has the same distance from the center of the div. I don't know if this makes sense but I will try to show what I mean with asterix symbols:

```
       *
    *     *
     *   *
```

## main-block {

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
border-radius: 250px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```

}

Comment: The second snippet in this answer could help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375780/div-elements-to-follow-a-curved-path-with-css3/32376885#32376885

Answer (score 0):

After Harry's useful link I believe this to be the solution even though I should perhaps clear redundant code (tried to move background-repeat: no-repeat and
background-size: initial; to div > div selector but that didn't work out so well...

index.html page:

```
<div id="main-block">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

style.css:

```
#main-block {

    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }

div > div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

div > div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  background: url(img/white-mana.png) center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: initial ;

}

div > div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
  background: url(img/blue-mana.png) center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: initial ;
}

div > div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(144deg);
  background: url(img/black-mana.png) center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: initial ;
}

div > div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(216deg);
  background: url(img/red-mana.png) center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: initial ;
}

div > div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(288deg);
  background: url(img/green-mana.png) center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: initial ;
}
```